# "Control versus Regulate "

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-difference, synonyms

Until now, I knew that regulate and control are synonyms and hence they can be used interchangeably. But now I am confused about it because of the following sentence:

> Production,distribution and sale will stay  in private hands, but the government  will control and regulate the whole process.

Please explain how we can use control and regulate as given in the above sentence. Is there  any difference  in their meaning?

Comment: You can regulate something, but relegate the control function to some other body. For instance, the legislature "regulates" legal relationships in the country by passing laws but has only a non-direct control over how exactly these laws are applied.

Comment: @CopperKettle, this comment provides a good point. Regarding relegation, I'd add that it may depend on the structure of the government/governing body. (+1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Regulate** and **control** are similar in meaning, but they are not exact synonyms.  When referring to government actions, the meaning of *regulate* is usually

> to make regulations for or concerning

(http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/regulate, definition 1b2)

*Control* is a little more general, and often is used to mean

> to exercise restraining or directing influence over

or

> to have power over

(http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/control, definitions 2a and 2b)

So the original sentence means something like: 
**Production, distribution and sale will stay in private hands, but the government will have power over the whole process and will make regulations concerning it.**

Comment: Would like to add that *regulate* (regulation) is heavily connected to legal matters (But the word regulator (i.e., valves etc.), is common in industrial processes). +1